# Python glob sort by filenames of unequal sizes

Tags: python, sorting, filepath, glob

I would like to retrieve a sorted list of files in a folder based on the filename.

The files names are of the format: xxxxxxxx_xxxxx(xx)_xx.data where x is a number. The second field may have length of 5 or 6 numbers.

`ls -l | top -5` gives:

```
20170914_135510_07.data
20170914_135510_34.data
20170914_135510_61.data
20170914_135510_88.data
20170914_135511_15.data
```

python `glob.glob(folder_path + "*.data")` gives:

```
20170914_140313_79.data
20170914_140011_11.data
20170914_140936_15.data
20170914_14019_39.data
20170914_140224_68.data
```

while `sorted(glob.glob(folder_path + "*.data"))` gives:

```
20170914_135510_07.data
20170914_135510_34.data
20170914_135510_61.data
20170914_135510_88.data
20170914_135511_15.data
```

I would like to get a result similar to ls *.data | sort -n -t _ -k1 -k2 -k3| head -n 5 which is:

```
20170914_13555_52.data
20170914_13555_80.data
20170914_13556_08.data
20170914_13556_34.data
20170914_13556_64.data
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what's different. Do you mean the quotes?

Comment: simple glob.glob orders the files randomly. sorted(glob.glob...) starts from 20170914_135510_07.data instead of 20170914_13555_52.data in other words it starts from the files with the max length (look at the second field). Fields may have variable lengths. For my example the first field is 8 digits second field is 4 to 6 digits last field is 2 digits. Fields are by convention the subparts formed with the _ separator.

Comment: So the issue is that you want a numeric sort on the second group, rather than a lexical sort?

Comment: Multiple numerical sorts, first for the first group then second then third.

Comment: Looks like you basically want to duplicate what that `sort` command is doing... split the filename (minus extension) on underscores, then convert the parts to int and use them as the sort key. You've got all the conceptual parts... which one exactly are you stuck on?